# Differential equation Euler substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was trying to solve this differential equation but can't figure out the final integral I get by variable separable method

> The equation is 
>   $$
> x^3 \, y' = y^3 + y^2 \, \sqrt{y^2-x^2}
> $$

I got the integral 
$$
\frac{dv}{v^3 + v^2 \sqrt{(v^2 - 1)} - v}
$$
but can't figure out how to solve it.

The Euler substitution $v= \frac{u^2 + 1}{2u}$ could work but I can't seem to proceed with it.

Any help with this problem is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try using Wolfram Alpha ?

Comment: Yes I tried Wolfram alpha . This seems to be an easy integral but I can't seem to figure it out. The final integral that I've posted needs to be solved but how ?

Comment: I think that Jeb made it !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I see a really fast answer to this.  Divide numerator and denominator by $v^3$.

$$\int\frac{v^{-3}dv}{1-v^{-2}+\sqrt{1-v^{-2}}}=\int\frac{v^{-3}dv}{(\sqrt{1-v^{-2}}+1)\sqrt{1-v^{-2}}}$$
$$t=\sqrt{1-v^{-2}}+1,dt=\frac{2v^{-3}dv}{2\sqrt{1-v^{-2}}}=\frac{v^{-3}dv}{\sqrt{1-v^{-2}}}$$

This drastically reduces the integral to $\int\frac{dt}t$.

Comment: you got the integrand wrong \frac{dv}{v^3 + v^2 \sqrt{(v^2 - 1)} - v}

Comment: @Curious Oops.  Don't know where those pluses came from.  I'll fix it.  Fortunately, it's just cosmetic.  Actually, it wouldn't come out that cleanly if it were a plus under the radical.

Comment: @Curious It should be correct now if you want to give it another look.

Comment: $$ \frac{dv}{v^3 + v^2 \sqrt{(v^2 - 1) }- v} $$ is the integral . So if you divide numerator and denominator by v^3, you will get $$ \int\frac{v^{-3}dv}{-v^{-2}+1+v^{-1}\sqrt{v^{2}-1}} $$

Comment: @Curious Or you do as I did.  $\frac{v^2\sqrt{v^2-1}}{v^3}=\frac{v^2}{v^2}\times\sqrt{\frac{v^2-1}{v^2}}=  \sqrt{1-v^{-2}}$

Comment: Don't know how I missed missed that! You're right.

Comment: But the above mentioned substitution will only change the integral to $$ \int\frac{(t-1)dt}{t-v^{-2}} $$ Ididn't understand how you get to $$\int\frac{dt}t $$

Comment: @Curious Added a small step, factoring the denominator.  Does this help?

Comment: Yes, don't know how I missed that one either. Thanks! This is indeed the easiest way around this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use a partial fraction decomposition to obtain:

$$ \int \frac{ dx}{x^3 + x^2 \sqrt{ x^2 -1} - x } = \int \frac{ \sqrt{x^2 -1} }{2 (x-1) } - \frac{ \sqrt{ x^2 - 1}}{ 2 (x+1)} - \frac{1}{x} dx$$

Use $u$ substitute with $x-1$ and $x+1$ since $x^2-1 = (x+1)(x-1)$. I think that should do it.

Comment: Well done ! Thanks.

Comment: @Jeb The partial decomposition doesn't yield the integral mentioned , right ? I tried doing it but it is (x-sqrt{x^2-1})/{x*sqrt(x^-1)}

Comment: That isn't right, my suggestion puts it in the form $ \sqrt{ (1 \pm 2/u )} du$ which looks like something I've done in the past. I don't remember how to solve it explicitly though

Comment: The partial decomposition mentioned does not yield L.H.S explicitly. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: It does, https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+fractions+%28+1%2F%28+x%5E3+%2B+x%5E2+sqrt%28x%5E2+-1%29+-x+%29

Comment: But when you try to do it manually, it doesn't yield L.H.S, right ? So does this mean that what you do manually                      (x-sqrt{x^2-1})/{x*sqrt(x^-1)} is also equal to L.H.S. ?

Comment: Is there any way to manually find the partial fractions ?

Answer (score -2):

$$ x^3 \, y' = y^3 + y \, \sqrt{y^2-x^2} $$
Let (y/x)=t, then: 
y = v*x; y' = x*v' + v

use this substitution

...and
v^3 + (v^2)*sqrt[v^2 - 1] - v = v*[(v^2 - 1) + sqrt(v^2 - 1)]

v^2 - 1 = p^2 => vdv = pdp

and you will get:

(dp)/[(p^2 +1)*(p + 1)] = dx/x

Comment: You have put                                         (y/x)*sqrt[(y/x)^2-1] but it was (R.H.S)/x^3.                     So it should be                                 (y/x^2)*sqrt[(y/x)^2-1] + (y/x)^3 = y'

Comment: I made ​​a start on the integral that you have specified.
there was v^3 + (v^2)*sqrt[(v^2 - 1) - v]
then my solving, of course, is not suitable for the initial condition

Comment: you've got y'= (y/x)^3 + (y/(x^2))*sqrt((y/x)^2 -1)
how u got v^3 + (v^2)*sqrt...?

Comment: v^3 + (v^2)*sqrt[(v^2 - 1)]- v

Comment: y/(x^2) is not equal to v^2

Comment: You have put (y/x)*sqrt[(y/x)^2-1] but it was (R.H.S)/x^3. So it should be (y/x^2)*sqrt[(y/x)^2-1] + (y/x)^3 = y' and the integral you get after the substitution y=vx is  dv/(v^3 + (v^2)*sqrt[(v^2 - 1)]- v)

Comment: not. from the initial conditions, after this replacement you do not get v^2.

Comment: @Alenka...See Mike's answer above.

Comment: sorry , the integral I posted was correct but the differential equation was not. According to what you have thought it to be, your answer is correct. Apologies.